# Yii mPDF css error

Tags: css, yii, frameworks, widget

I have read some posts about how to add css style in mPDF, I am using Yii framework and I tried many ways with no result, any idea about how to make it work?

```
$this->layout="//layouts/pdf";
        $mPDF = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf();
        $html = $this->render('pdf', array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider), true);

        $stylesheet = file_get_contents(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/css/print.css');
        $stylesheet .= file_get_contents(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/css/main.css');

        $mPDF->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
        $mPDF->WriteHTML($html, 2);

        $mPDF->Output('Inmuebles',EYiiPdf::OUTPUT_TO_BROWSER);
```

Thats the controller code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/print.css" media="print" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/main.css" />
```

Thats the code in the layout/pdf

Error:

```
file_get_contents(/yii/yiitest/css/print.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way (in the controller), it worked for me:

```
$mPDF = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf();
$html = $this->render('pdf', array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider), true);

$stylesheet = file_get_contents(/* path to first css file */);
$stylesheet .= file_get_contents(/* path to second css file */);

$mPDF->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
$mPDF->WriteHTML($html, 2);

echo $mPDF->Output('Inmuebles',EYiiPdf::OUTPUT_TO_BROWSER);
```

Comment: file_get_contents(/yii/yiitest/css/print.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory, but the file exists

Comment: try it this way:
file_get_contents(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') . /*path to your css file from the project root*/)
as the webroot is the actual path of your project root.

Comment: $stylesheet = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../../css/print.css');
  $stylesheet .= file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../../css/main.css'); this is how i fixed it, but thank you very much!